# Everytime when I dismiss my action sheet, it goes back to the very beginning. #swiftui

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, actionsheet

Everytime when I dismiss my action sheet, it goes back to the very beginning.
Dismiss button below:

```
Button{
  showingSheet.toggle()
}label: {
  HStack {
    Text("At the movies")
    Spacer()
  }
  .padding()
  .background(Color(colorScheme == .dark ?   
  .tertiarySystemBackground: .white))
}
.sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
  StatusSelectorView()
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'it goes back to the very beginning'. Please show all relevant code. From your provided code it is not clear where the problem is. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I think he means that it's de-initialized.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.